# Rails 4: Results of form submission not saving in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I have a form set up to create an `exercise`.  The `schema.rb` file shows the database structure:

```
 create_table "exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "seconds"
    t.integer  "weight"
    t.integer  "reps"
    t.integer  "workout_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "needs_seconds"
    t.integer  "needs_weight"
    t.integer  "needs_reps"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

  add_index "exercises", ["user_id"], name: "index_exercises_on_user_id"
  add_index "exercises", ["workout_id"], name: "index_exercises_on_workout_id"
```

Here's the `_form` that creates the `exercise`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
    <%= form_for [@workout, @exercise] do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :workout_id, value: @workout.id %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter exercise name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_seconds, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_seconds, class: 'check_box' %> Report seconds?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_reps, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_reps, class: 'check_box' %> Report reps?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
        <p><%= f.label :needs_weight, class: 'sr-only' %>
        <%= f.check_box :needs_weight, class: 'check_box' %> Report weight?</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Create Exercise", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know the exercise name at least is being saved, because I am able to call this on the `exercises#index` and have it render properly:

```
<h1>Current Exercises:</h1>
      <% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
        <p><%= exercise.name %> (<%= link_to "Delete #{exercise.name}", workout_exercise_path(@workout, exercise), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>)</p>
      <% end %>
```

However, this code on the `workouts#show` page (a workout `has_many` exercises, an exercise `has_many` reports) shows the exercise names, but does not show the appropriate checkboxes:

```
    <% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>
      <%= render 'reports/form', report: @report, exercise: exercise %>
```

And here's `reports/_form`:

```
<%= form_for report,
  :url => { :controller => "reports",
  :action => :create,
  :workout_id => @workout.id,
  :exercise_id => exercise.id } do |f| %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-push-1">
    <p>Enter Your Results for <strong><%= exercise.name %></strong>:</p>
    <div class="row">
    <% if exercise.needs_reps == "1" %>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <%= f.label :reps %>
        <%= f.number_field :reps, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if exercise.needs_seconds == "1" %>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <%= f.label :seconds%>
        <%= f.number_field :seconds, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if exercise.needs_weight == "1" %>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <%= f.label :weight %>
        <%= f.number_field :weight, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </div> <!-- row -->
    <div class="text-right"><%= f.submit "Record Results", class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
  <% end %>
</div> <!-- columns -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

However, even though the exercise name shows up via `<%= exercise.name %>`, when I look in the console for `Exercise.where(id: 1)` I get this:

```
[2] pry(main)> Exercise.where(id: 1)
  Exercise Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
=> []
```

Which doesn't show any of the variables you can see I've added in (as seen in `schema.rb`).

Can anyone help me detangle this mystery?

ADDED INFO:

Here are the server logs for when I access the `workouts#show` page:

```
Started GET "/workouts/d" for ::1 at 2016-06-05 14:45:32 -0700
Processing by WorkoutsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"d"}
  Workout Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "workouts".* FROM "workouts" WHERE "workouts"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "workouts"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "d"]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?  [["workout_id", 4]]
  Exercise Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" WHERE "exercises"."workout_id" = ?  [["workout_id", 4]]
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered reports/_form.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Report Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 13]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Report Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 14]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Report Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 15]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Report Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 16]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Report Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "reports".* FROM "reports" WHERE "reports"."exercise_id" = ?  [["exercise_id", 17]]
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered workouts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (22.4ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

And here's the `workouts_controller.rb`, which I believe has jurisdiction where the problem is occurring:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @most_recent_workout = Workout.order("created_at").last
  end

  def show
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @exercise = Exercise.new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def create
    @workout = Workout.new(workout_params)
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
      flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @workout.user_id = current_user
  end

  def update
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
    @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
    @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
    @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
    @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
    @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
    @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
    @workout.user = current_user

    if @workout.save
       flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
      redirect_to @workout
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @workout = Workout.friendly.find(params[:id])

    if @workout.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
      redirect_to action: :index
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
      render :show
    end
  end

  private
  def workout_params
    params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :workout_type, :teaser, :description, :video, :difficulty, :trainer, :slug, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you add logs? also code for controller?

Comment: @curiousmind, So added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, this turned out to be something fairly simple.  Instead of:

```
<% if exercise.needs_weight == "1" %>
```

I had to put:

```
<% if exercise.needs_weight? %>
```

And the checkboxes displayed.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to inform people this has already been solved.

Comment: It won't let me until tomorrow.